# How to make a sidebar sticky on scroll?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm using [these](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/FlexStart/blog.html) Bootstrap themes, but I could not get the sidebar as a sticky sidebar when scrolling.

Comment: No research? No effort? No answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight loophole in your code. As we all know that `position:sticky` only support when there is no parent element has `overflow:hidden`. I reviewed your site and found a few errors.

1  `.blog .sidebar` has no property as `position: sticky`. Please add it. like this.

```
.blog .sidebar {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 60px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: sticky; // Newly Added CSS
  top: 0; // Newly added css
}
```

2  Remove `overflow:hidden` from section css like this.

```
section {
    padding: 60px 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */ // Remove this.
}
```

Thanks me later.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a custom stylesheet specifying the sidebar style or you can add an inline CSS code "position: sticky" to your sidebar element/container.

With the former, add a custom class to your sidebar container (e.g. `<div class="stickySidebar"><ul>...</ul></div>`) and add `position:sticky` in your CSS stylesheet:

```
.stickySidebar{ position: sticky; }
```

or if you want to see the result without doing those steps, add an inline CSS in your sidebar container:

```
<div class="sidebar" style="position: sticky;">
```